# jquery AJAX REST reinitialize datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, sharepoint-2013

I have a little bit of code that i can't seem to get right.  I'm very new at this and just trying to do the best I can so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.  I have a simple AJAX code to pull some information from a Sharepoint list.

I have 2 buttons that when I click one I get one set of information loaded in the table and when I click the other I get a different set of information.  Unfortunately I can't get it so I can click one, get the info and when I click the second it should wipe the table and replace with the new information, both work but you have to refresh the page between clicks.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I've searched high and low on the web and found a lot of "solutions" to this problem but none seemed to work for me.  See code below.

```
function ButtonFunction(input) {
var call = $.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items?$select=Title,Column4,Column7&$filter=(Column6 eq '"+input+"')&$top=5000",
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }
    });

    call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "bDestroy":true,
            "bProcessing":true,
            "aaData":data.d.results,
            "aoColuns": [
                    {"mData": "Title" },
                    {"mData": "Column4" },
                    {"mData": "Column7" },
        ]
    });
});

call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error" + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all.  Apparently I had an old version of datatables.css  When i linked to the latest version everything just worked the way it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all rows from a table:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table.rows().remove()


function ButtonFunction(input) {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table.rows().remove()
var call = $.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('List1')/items?$select=Title,Column4,Column7&$filter=(Column6 eq '"+input+"')&$top=5000",
type:"GET",
dataType: "json",
headers: {
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}
});

call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "bDestroy":true,
        "bProcessing":true,
        "aaData":data.d.results,
        "aoColuns": [
                {"mData": "Title" },
                {"mData": "Column4" },
                {"mData": "Column7" },
    ]
  });
});

  call.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus,errorThrown){
  alert("Error" + jqXHR.responseText);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, where in the code would i put that?  Sorry, like I said I'm very new at this but really appreciate it.

Comment: I tried that one, it didn't work.  I lose access to even the initial pull of information, it just shows a blank table even when i click.